# Need help finding a bounding function to apply dominated convergence theorem

Tags: integration

Let $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that  if $f$ is continuous and bounded, then so is $f*g$, the convolution of $f$ with $g$.

I'm showing continuity of $f*g$ using convergent sequences.

Letting $x_n\to x$, it follows that $f(y-x_n)g(y)$ is a function of $y$ that converges to $f(y-x)g(y)$ (by continuity of $f$). Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f*g)(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f(y-x_n)g(y) dm.$$

I would like to continue by saying that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f(y-x_n)g(y) dm = \int\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y-x_n)g(y) dm = \int f(y-x)g(y)dm = (f*g)(x),$$

but I need an integrable function that dominates each $f(y-x_n)g(y)$ before I can pass the limit under the integral.

Thanks in advance for sharing any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is given to be bounded. If $|f| \leq M$ then $|f(y-x_n)g(y)| \leq M|g(y)|$ and $M|g|$ is integrable.

Comment: Ha. Of course. thanks for the suggestion.